# How to get data using php and angylarJS

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I hope that you are in good mood :). I'm trying to return data which depend on text from user using AngularJS and php. So I create file php which contain my query and using $http.get in AngularJS. My problem is I want to integrate value of input in mysql query, but always using angular. I tried many times but nothing works To be more clear, here is muy code:

app.js

```
app1.controller('autoCompleteCTRL',function($scope,$rootScope,$http) {
    $scope.search = function(){
        $scope.$watch('searchText', function() {
            console.log($scope.searchText);
        });
        $http({
            method: "get",
            url: "../SearchResultsQuery.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { 'userText': $scope.searchText},
            async: false,
            params: {action: "get"}
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert(data);
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {           
            alert(error);               
        });
    };
}
```

index.html

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search for items" id="textFiled" class="input"  ng-model="searchText" ng-change="search()" />
```

app.php

```
<?php

$conn=pgsqlCon();
$searchText = mysql_real_escape_string(userText);
$query='SELECT * FROM planet_osm_roads AS a, to_tsquery_partial(\'%.$searchText.%\') AS query
WHERE ts_road @@ query';
$result = pg_query($conn,$query);
$myarray = array();
while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {
    $myarray[] = $row;
}
pg_close($conn);
echo json_encode($myarray);

?>
```

I hope that you understand me Thanks for advance :)

Comment: check this http://www.keyboardninja.eu/webdevelopment/a-simple-search-with-angularjs-and-php

Comment: First thankx for your help. I have already read this article, but I don't understand the use of file_get_contents("php://input"). I write my query in php file, so do I need to use this line?

Comment: PS: I'm not using json data, I'm just want to read the input with angularJS and Integrate this variable in the query

Answer (score 2):

try to make your http request like this:

```
app.controller('TestCtrl', function ($scope, $http){

    $scope.search = function(){
        $http.post('../app.php', {searchText: $scope.searchText})
        .success(function (response){
            console.log(response);
        })
        .error(function (response){
            console.log(response);
        });
    }

});
```

app.php

```
<?php
    $data = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $searchText = mysql_real_escape_string($data['searchText']);
    /* database code */
?>
```

This should work.

Comment: I got the same error " POST 500 (Internal Server Error)". I think because I write $data = file_get_contents("php://input"). What is the purpose of using this line?

Comment: Can you help me please?. I tried manu time but it didn't work :(

Comment: php://input is a stream that allows you to read raw data from the request body. and you want to use $_GET to retrieve your data then check @nostop solution. and for 500 error you must have an error in your php code.

Comment: You are right @Ayoub Oulaika, I have problem in php file. When I tried to put for example params: { 'userText': 'rabat'} and in query to replace to_tsquery_partial(\'%.$searchText.%\') with this :  to_tsquery_partial(\'%rabat%\'), it's working, so the problem is the syntax of the variable inside query. I tried many expressions but it's not working :(

Comment: When I try to add: if(isset($_GET['userText'])) {$user=$_GET['userText'];} and in query: to_tsquery_partial(\'%$user%\'), there is no error but nothing display

Answer (score 1):

1. In your **app.js** file, instead of this line:

> data: { 'userText': $scope.searchText}

write:

> **params**: { 'userText': $scope.searchText}

and remove this line:

> params: {action: "get"}

This way it will transfer userText variable through request URL as a GET parameter.

2. In your **app.php** file, instead of:

> $searchText = mysql_real_escape_string(userText);

write:

> $searchText = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['userText']);

This will populate your $searchText php variable with text from client application (AngularJS). I'm not sure about your postgresql query. Your question title is **mysql - How to get data...**, but in your php code sample you use postgres extension to build query. But that's a different story I guess.

Comment: Hi, thankx for your help, I will try that now. Ah yes, I use postgres database

Comment: I got the same error. I think the problem is in this line: $searchText = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['userText']). What do you think?

Comment: To tell for sure, I need to see what error you get. There could be many reasons. Now I see that inside your angularjs application url you request different script name than **app.php**. May be this is the reason? Another thing, if you want to check whether server script is working fine, simply type in your browser address bar: http://your-domain.name/app.php?userText=test .This will execute script directly. If you do not see error, maybe you can add error_reporting(E_ALL); line at the top of your php script.

Comment: I'm just write 'app.php' in post  but I'm using the correct file. I do a change instead of $searchText = mysql_escape_string ($_GET['userText']) I write $searchText = pg_escape_string ($_GET['userText']), and no error but I don't get any data

Comment: I'm still stuck in this issue :'(

Comment: I figure out that the syntax to_tsquery_partial(\'%.$searchText.%\') is incorrect, I tried many attempts but no one works :(